# Php вырезает параметры url при редиректе

Tags: php, html, redirect, http-redirect

как сделать чтобы php не обрезал параметры строки, сейчас после редиректа получается он обрезает конец строки и **&site=123** не попадает. Подсказывают что можно попробовать **urlencode** но как практически сделать, не знаю прошу помочь.

```html
<?=
    $getutm = $_GET['utm_source'];
    $string = 'https://example.com/?tag=123'.$getutm.'&site=123';
    urlencode($string);
    ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=<?= $string; ?>">
  </head>

  <body></body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Вам нужен редирект? Вместо `urlencode($string);` вставьте это `header('Location: '.$string); exit;`

Comment: Ах да, `urlencode($string);` так не работает, `$string = urlencode($string);` - так будет ;)

Answer (score 1):

Вот альтернативный способ делать редирект напрямую из PHP

```
<?php
$getutm = urlencode($_GET['utm_source']);
$url = 'https://example.com/?tag=123&utm_source=' . $getutm . '&site=123';
header('Location: ' . $url);
```

Согласно вопросы и коду, уверен что в GET переменной неверные данные приходят. Каждый GET параметр в строке должен быть разделен амперсандом (**&**).
Сделай `var_dump($_GET['utm_source'])` и посмотри что пришло

Проверь это значение на наличие спецсимволов, тебе нужно ее экранировать от спецсимволов, а не всю строку.
*В примере я не делал проверку на переменную, подразумевается что она всегда имеет значение*

Comment: vardump получается такой: `string(5) "news4"`, а параметр '&site=123' все равно обрезается.

Comment: Попробуй поменять местами параметры: `$url = 'https://example.com/?tag=123&site=123&utm_source=' . $getutm;` Посмотри что в данном случае будет делать?